# Is it possible to outhouse ShutdownStrategy for CamelContext into a central OSGi bundle?

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to outhouse central beans of my OSGi bundles into a central bundle, which provides them as a service. This works fine with the ErrorHanlders and Processors, but not with the [ShutdownStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.html) and [RedeliveryPolicy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/RedeliveryPolicy.html). The Error Message I receive is

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: A class org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy was found in the interfaces list, but class proxying is not allowed by default. The ext:proxy-method='classes' attribute needs to be added to this service reference.
```

I could try to follow the instrutction and add the `ext:proxy-method`, but first I want to understand the clue here. Maybe it's not a good idea to centralize strategies and policies?

**[EDIT]** The mistake here was to use the `class` in the service instead of an `interface`. So `interface="org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy"` should be the correct Interface here (for the ShutdownStrategy). The bundle with my camel route references this service so:

```
<reference
    id="shutdownStrategy"
    interface="org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy"
    component-name="shutdownStrategy" />
```

But now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified
```

**[EDIT]** I want to confine this question to the **ShutdownStrategy**, because the *RedeliveryPolicy* works fine when I referenc it in the ErrorHandlers inside my central bundle.

So is it possible to outhouse the **ShutdownStrategy**, too? Maybe not, because [it needs a CamelContext](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html#GracefulShutdown-ShutdownStrategy).

> When using Spring XML you then just define a spring bean which implements the org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy and Camel will look it up at startup and use it instead of its default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/graceful-shutdown.html#GracefulShutdown-ShutdownStrategy)

> You can implement your own strategy to control the shutdown by implementing the `org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy` and the set it on the CamelContext using the setShutdownStrategy method.
>
> When using Spring XML you then just define a spring bean which implements the `org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy` and Camel will look it up at startup and use it instead of its default.

So if you have your own implementation of the ShutdownStrategy you can use it as a bean.

```
<bean id="shutdownStrategy"
    class="org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy">
</bean>
```